# Flickering Sprite in Pygame

Tags: python, image, pygame, frame-rate, flicker

I know lots of people have had issues with flickering images in pygame on here, but none of the responses have helped me. I am trying to make Space Invaders, however, the bullet flickers as it moves up the screen. Please try to help me, and thank you! *I do not currently care about the size, position, or scale of the bullet, I know it does not look great, but I just want it to display properly!* Below is the code:

```
import pygame
#import sys- might use later
import random

#Sets the starting values for screen, etc. of the playing space
pygame.init()
size = (800, 600)
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)
pygame.display.set_caption("Space Invaders")
play = True
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
blkColor = (0, 0, 0)

#Loads and sizes the alien and player ship(s)
playerShip = pygame.image.load('ship.png')
playerShip = pygame.transform.scale(playerShip, (50, 50))
playerX = 370
playerY = 520
alien = pygame.image.load('alien.png')
alien = pygame.transform.scale(alien, (35, 35))
alienX = random.randint(0, 750)
alienY = 0
move = 5
alienMove = 5
bullet = pygame.image.load('bullet.png')
bullet = pygame.transform.scale(bullet, (5, 100))
bulletX = 0
bulletY = 600
hit = False
fire = False
hitRangeMin = -35
hitRangeMax = 35
score = 0


def player():
    screen.blit(playerShip, (playerX, playerY))

def enemy():
    screen.blit(alien, (alienX, alienY))

def alienMovement():
    global alienX
    global alienY
    global alienMove
#Moves the alien across the screen; when it hits the edge, it shifts down one spot and goes the other direction
    alienX += alienMove
    if alienX > 750:
        alienMove = -5
        alienY += 35
    if alienX < 0:
        alienMove = 5
        alienY += 35

def shoot(x, y):
    global fire
    global bulletY
    fire = True
    screen.blit(bullet, (x, y))
    pygame.display.flip()
    if bulletY < 0:
        fire = False
        bulletY = 550
    elif bulletY >= 0:
        fire = True

def gameOver(score):
    print('Will add score and display and stuff- does noo matter.')

# Keeps the game window open until exited
while not hit:

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            quit()

    player()
    enemy()

    key_input = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if key_input[pygame.K_LEFT]:
        playerX -= move
    elif key_input[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
        playerX += move

    if playerX > 800:
        playerX = 0
    if playerX < 0:
        playerX = 800

    #For shooting the bullet
    if key_input[pygame.K_SPACE]:
        bulletX = playerX + 23
        shoot(bulletX, bulletY)
##Loops with function "shoot" to move bullet up the screen
    if fire:
        shoot(bulletX, bulletY)
        bulletY -= 5


    screen.fill(blkColor)
    alienMovement()
    player()
    enemy()
    pygame.display.flip()
    clock.tick(60)
```

Comment: Is the problem solved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is caused by multiple calls to [`pygame.display.update()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.update). An update of the display at the end of the application loop is sufficient. Multiple calls to `pygame.display.update()` or `pygame.display.flip()` cause flickering.

Remove `pygame.display.flip()` from `shoot`:

```py
def shoot(x, y):
    global fire
    global bulletY
    fire = True
    screen.blit(bullet, (x, y))
    
    # pygame.display.flip()            <--- DELETE
    
    if bulletY < 0:
        fire = False
        bulletY = 550
    elif bulletY >= 0:
        fire = True
```

And you have to clear the screen **before** drawing the bullet:

```py
while not hit:
    # [...]

    screen.fill(blkColor)             # <--- INSERT

    if key_input[pygame.K_SPACE]:
        bulletX = playerX + 23
        shoot(bulletX, bulletY)
##Loops with function "shoot" to move bullet up the screen
    if fire:
        shoot(bulletX, bulletY)
        bulletY -= 5

    # screen.fill(blkColor)            <--- DELETE

    alienMovement()
    player()
    enemy()
    pygame.display.flip()
    clock.tick(60)
```